# Can I export mail rules from Outlook for Apple Mac to G Suite?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, export

I'm an Outlook user for Mac and migrating soon to GSuite. I have a load of mail rules to keep my inbox tidy but I cant see how to export mail rules which I can then import into GSuite.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not realizable.Outlook for mac doesn't have an option to import/export rules. You can vote this thread in UserVoice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/15139845-import-export-of-rules-rwz-file

Comment: thanks - is there a script that can be run at all? Those mail rules must be stored somewhere! :-)